# What does it mean WCHAN 'finish' in ps -l <proc_id> output?

Tags: linux, ssh, ps

I'm running a number of ssh commands in a background. When the triggered-via-ssh
command finishes to run, the appropriate background ssh process doesn't get 
terminated and its ps -l output shows 'finish' for WCHAN and T for 'state'.
So why the triggering process is not terminated and what does it mean 'finish' value
for WCHAN?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide the full ssh command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state "T" means that the process was suspended.  Since you said you ran it in the background, this may be due to reading tty input (or writing tty output if stty tostop is set).  If the program does not require any input, use the ssh -n option to avoid this.

Comment: I guess it's it - I ran the ssh command without -n flag. Thanks a lot.